# Бесплатная доставка при достижнении определенной суммы в woocommerce и другое

Tags: wordpress, cms, woocommerce

В Woocommerce уже часть сайта сделал, на этом месте остановился:

1. Как сделать бесплатную доставку при заказе от 1000 руб?
2. Как до 1000 рублей сделать в 200,
3. И чтобы к загрузке можно было прилагать фото.

Comment: Эт вопрос, или реклама? И куда писать, мне как раз ботинки починить надо. _(Нужно задать вопрос более подробно, описать что уже сделано, что при этом сделать не удалось, здесь не сообщество фрилансеров с избытком свободного времени)_

Comment: 1)Вопрос
2)Проблема
3)Решение

Comment: ну я уже часть сайта сделал, на этом месте остановился

Comment: Ваш вопрос должен иметь вид:"Как сделать бесплатную доставку при заказе от 1000 руб?
Как до 1000 рублей сделать в 200, И чтобы к загрузке можно было прилагать фот. "
Суть я думаю вы поняли?

Comment: Ну я думаю, что можно в ином виде. У людей бывают разные виды мышлений

Comment: Стоит научиться задавать ВОПРОСЫ. Если, конечно хочется получать ответы. Большая удача найти того, у кого телепатическая извилина может войти в резонанс с подобными потоком сознания. 2 "вопроса" без единого вопроса.. нда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В админке: WooCommerce - Настройки - Доставка - Зоны доставки. Создать зону доставки (скажем, Россия или город). Потом к зоне доставки добавить метод доставки "Бесплатная доставка". Отредактировать этот метод доставки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там можно указать сумму минимального заказа (1000 руб) для бесплатной доставки.

До 1000 руб - указать в стоимости доставки, как обычно.